# @ElementCollection for persisting a Set<Long>

Tags: hibernate, set

I have the following ElementCollection on my object

```
public class MyObject {

@ElementCollection(targetClass=Long)
Set<Long> otherIds

}
```

This should create a table with values

```
myObj_id   other_id
1            2
1            3
2            4
3            4
```

But it only creates the fllowing rows

```
 myObj_id   other_id
    1            2
    1            3
    2            4
```

Something makes me think it is not allowing the repeating value '4' in the other_id column
But Im not sure why, I tried the followin

- Flushing the session before closing
- Commiting transaction
- Using cascadeType SAVE_UPDATE
- Tried using List instead of Set
- Tried setting FetchType.EAGER

  what have I missed?

Here is the save code

```
public MyObj createOrSave(MyObj obj) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {


      session.beginTransaction();
      session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

      session.getTransaction().rollback();
      throw e;
    } finally {
      if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();

      }
    }

    return obj;
  }
```

Looking at the table structure, this creates both myObj_id and other_id as primary keys, is this the problem?

I added more logs and it looks like, just before saving the entity the second time, the id for other_id is null. Not sure what that means but it seems odd

Comment: looking in the LOG would tell you what is happening. The DB structure of the 2 tables would also assist in your debugging. No persistence code is posted showing what objects are present before persist, so no comment is possible. No idea what is "SAVE_UPDATE", this is not part of JPA.

Comment: Thanks I added the save code, and dont see anything in the debug logs,

Comment: teh SAVE_UPDATE is hibernate not JPA, I found on SO that people were using it to fix similar issues